# Can working WKWebView from share point url?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, sharepoint

Version : XCode 6.1 beta

Backend : Sharepoint 2013

Example code for doubt below

Call to viewDidLoad

```
    WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.eyWebView.frame configuration:theConfiguration];
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    NSString *eUrl = [[EYUtility share] encodingUrlWithString:<-sharepoint url->;
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:eUrl]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

After viewDidLoad to Call to didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge

```
-(void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler{
    if (challenge.previousFailureCount == 0){
        NSURLCredentialPersistence persistence = NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession;
        NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"username" password:@"password" persistence:persistence];
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential,credential);
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"%s: challenge.error = %@", __FUNCTION__, challenge.error);
        completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeCancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil);
    }
}
```

After call Authentication challenge then called to didFinishNavigation. The wkWebview showed "Please wait...". Not showed from share point url.

Why not show it from share point url.

Answer (score 0):

Here i use UIWebview with CustomHTTPProtocol class. it will working from sharepoint url.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CustomHTTPProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html

Cheer :-)

Comment: The OP asked for an example with WKWebView though, not UIWebView.